# Getting headers from MJPEG stream

Tags: javascript, image, http-headers, mjpeg

I'm working in a (Python) MJPEG server and I want to add a custom header (specifying the image timestamp) to every image I send.

The problem is that I'm loading the MJPEG stream directly in a HTML < img >, so I guess I can't get the images headers.

Is there some way to do it? I tried with XMLHttpRequest and getting the responseText, but it keeps in memory the complete MJPEG stream, and it could be a serious problem...